# qemu: delvm causes image corruption

Tags: command, boot, qemu

I am using qemu-0.14, as a part of marss cycle-accurate simulator http://marss86.org/~marss86/index.php/Home.

When I use delvm for deleting a snapshot, it corrupts the whole image. After it, the image no longer boots.

Is there a solution to it (a patch or a recent version that solves it). Please let me know.
I tried to ask on qemu-forum, but could not get a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user from qemu provided the following answer:

> Please try if commit 35d7ace7 fixes it. The 0.15.0 release contains
>   this fix. (The fix is about loadvm, but you probably used that, too)
>
> If it doesn't help, please describe in more details what you do
>   between image creation and the visible corruption. You can use
>   'qemu-img check' in order to detect corruption as early as possible.